# cloudstack No suitable hosts found under this Cluster

Tags: apache-cloudstack

When I try to start an instance through template,I get the following error messages:

```
2013-11-10 19:44:28,716 DEBUG [cloud.deploy.DeploymentPlanningManagerImpl] (Job-Executor-5:job-19 = [ d070b5ba-f342-4252-9137-4d2c1b19eca6 ]) No suitable hosts found under this Cluster: 2
2013-11-10 19:44:28,718 DEBUG [cloud.deploy.DeploymentPlanningManagerImpl] (Job-Executor-5:job-19 = [ d070b5ba-f342-4252-9137-4d2c1b19eca6 ]) Could not find suitable Deployment Destination for this VM under any clusters, returning.
2013-11-10 19:44:28,718 DEBUG [cloud.deploy.FirstFitPlanner] (Job-Executor-5:job-19 = [ d070b5ba-f342-4252-9137-4d2c1b19eca6 ]) Searching all possible resources under this Zone: 1
2013-11-10 19:44:28,718 DEBUG [cloud.deploy.FirstFitPlanner] (Job-Executor-5:job-19 = [ d070b5ba-f342-4252-9137-4d2c1b19eca6 ]) Listing clusters in order of aggregate capacity, that have (atleast one host with) enough CPU and RAM capacity under this Zone: 1
```

I feel confused because I already have a host in cluster 2.
Can anyone give me some suggestions?Any reply will be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have a closer look at the log file to understand why the CloudStack is unable to place a VM on the host.  The information will appear above the entries you have provided.  There are a lot of issues that can cause this problem.

E.g. [this blog entry walks through a configuration problem with XenServer](http://dlafferty.blogspot.nl/2013/08/using-cloudstacks-log-files-xenserver.html)

Another common issue is when using local storage, you need to create a new compute offering that uses local storage disks.  The default compute offerings do not support local storage.

Updated:  changed answer to take into account that your sample is from the log file.

Answer (score 1):

Most probably you are running out of capacity or due to some other error cloudstack has added you host in the "**Avoid List**". It does that when the management server finds an error while deploying the instance and from the next time till the problem gets resolved, the host and the cluster will be part of avoid list and will be avoided in the subsequent deployments.

You need to find out the exact reason by **monitoring the management server logs**. Login to your management server and go to folder **/var/log/cloudstack/management/**.

Now run the command **tail -f management-server.log**

This will give you continuous output of the management server log, so that you know what exactly is happening at the moment.

Now **do the operation on UI (e.g. try to add instance) and quickly monitor the running logs**.

Abort the command when you find an exception in the log and monitor the log statements just above the exception.

Also as a standard practice, always have a habit of monitoring the management server logs and agent logs (on host - /var/log/cloudstack/agent/agent.log)